# Difference between real fft and complex fft with imaginary part of zero in fftw?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, fftw

I have a real 2d matrix. I am taking its fft using `fftw`. But the result of using a real to complex fft is different from a complex ( with imaginary part equal to zero) to complex fft.

real matrix

```
 0     1     2
 3     4     5
 6     7     8
```

result of real to complex fft

```
36 -4.5+2.59808i  -13.5+7.79423i 
0  -13.5-7.79423i 0 
0  0              0
```

Code:

```
int r = 3, c = 3;
int sz = r * c;
double *in = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double) * sz);
fftw_complex *out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * sz);
fftw_plan p = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(r, c, in, out, FFTW_MEASURE);
for ( int i=0; i<r; ++i ){
    for ( int j=0; j<c; ++j ){
        in[i*c+j] = i*c + j;
    }
}
fftw_execute(p);
```

**using a complex matrix with imaginary part of zero**

complex matrix

```
 0+0i     1+0i     2+0i
 3+0i     4+0i     5+0i
 6+0i     7+0i     8+0i
```

result of complex to complex fft

```
36               -4.5 + 2.59808i  -4.5 - 2.59808i 
-13.5 + 7.79423i 0               0 
-13.5 - 7.79423i 0               0
```

Code:

```
int r = 3, c = 3;
int sz = r * c;
fftw_complex *out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * sz);
fftw_complex *inc = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * sz);
p = fftw_plan_dft_2d( r,c, inc, out, FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_MEASURE);
for ( int i=0; i<r; ++i ){
    for ( int j=0; j<c; ++j ){
        inc[i*c+j][0] = i*c+j;
        inc[i*c+j][1] = 0;
    }
}
fftw_execute(p);
```

I am after the result of complex to complex fft. But the real to complex fft is much faster and my data is real. Am I making a programming mistake or the result should be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in [FFTW documentation](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html#Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data)

> Then, after an r2c transform, the output is an n<sub>0</sub> × n<sub>1</sub> × n<sub>2</sub> × … × (n<sub>d-1</sub>/2 + 1) array of `fftw_complex` values in row-major order

In other words, the output for your real-to-complex transform of your sample real matrix really is:

```
 36            -4.5+2.59808i
-13.5+7.79423i  0
-13.5-7.79423i  0
```

You may notice that these two columns match exactly the first two columns of your complex-to-complex transform. The missing column is omitted from the real-to-complex transform since it is redundant due to symmetry. As such, the full 3x3 matrix including the missing column could be constructed using:

```
fftw_complex *outfull = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * sz);
int outc = (c/2+1);
for ( int i=0; i<r; ++i ){
    // copy existing columns
    for ( int j=0; j<outc; ++j ){
        outfull[i*c+j][0] = out[i*outc+j][0];
        outfull[i*c+j][1] = out[i*outc+j][1];
    }
    // generate missing column(s) from symmetry
    for ( int j=outc; j<c; ++j){
        int row = (r-i)%r;
        int col = c-j;
        outfull[i*c+j][0] =  out[row*outc+col][0];
        outfull[i*c+j][1] = -out[row*outc+col][1];
    }
}
```